# log4j2 in Wildfly 9

Tags: java, wildfly, log4j2

I use log4j2 as my default logging, when I run my webapp with Wildfly, My logs get wrapped as an INFO like follows:

**17:28:31,127 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)** DEBUG 2015-10-15 17:28:31,127 za.co.manticore.core.aspect.cacing.CachingAspect - Entering Caching Aspect for method getApplicationMeta

This is causing my logs to be cluttered, as all my logs are logged as INFO. How can I configure Wildfly to not do this. I have done some googleing but could not find an answer that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you can configure Wildfly not to wrap your **stdout** and **stderr** logs.
Run the following CLI commands

`sh jboss-cli.sh --connect '/subsystem=logging/console-handler=JUST-PRINT:add(formatter="%s%E%n")'`

`sh jboss-cli.sh --connect '/subsystem=logging/logger=stderr:add(use-parent-handlers="false", handlers=[JUST-PRINT])'`

`sh jboss-cli.sh --connect '/subsystem=logging/logger=stdout:add(use-parent-handlers="false", handlers=[JUST-PRINT])'`

Comment: There's no real reason for the `%E` there and you'd only need to do `stderr` if the console handler or appender uses `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should properly configure log4j2. It looks like currently it has console appender - try remove console appender from log4j2 config